# Tag Clean up: The [static] tag could do with some attention

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

The [static](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static) tag could do with some attention again. It was cleaned up back in 2012, but over the years has crept back.

It looks like it's been used for several purposes and could mean things like [static-typing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-typing), [static-data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-data) etc.

So can you check out the questions with the tag and retag and edit and vote to close where appropriate.

Once the tag has been cleaned up, we can look at blacklisting.

Comment: 23 remaining questions look pretty tough to re-tag in a meaningful way. Some of these make me wish there was tag like **"static-access"** or something like that...

Comment: @gnat - feel free to create new tags if you think they're needed.

Comment: well it took me a while to figure this one and frankly, I was still pondering if it's OK when posting previous comment. Now, since it didn't make you vomit :) I think I'll go for it. I plan tag wiki excerpt for it like "in object-oriented programming, access from a static (class) context, as opposed to one from a particular object instance context"

Comment: @ChrisF The tag still exists. It has 51 questions. It needs to be cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, [static](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static) is empty.

Most of the (40+) questions that were there few days ago have been retagged to either of more specific tags such as [static-analysis](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis), [static-methods](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-methods), [static-access](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-access), [static-keyword](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-keyword), [static-linking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-linking).

It is expected that the [tag will disappear in 24 hours](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18021).

Comment: You sir, are a hero.

Comment: And now, it still exists and has 51 questions.